# Access dates in Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add timestamps from firestore to populate a calendar. The calendar is this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_calendar_carousel)

```
Future<void> getCalendarEventList() async {
    await Firestore.instance.collection('availableDates').snapshots().listen(
            (data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) => _markedDateMap.add(
            new DateTime(doc['availableDates']),
            new Event(
                date:DateTime(doc['availableDates']),
                title: 'hello',
                icon: _eventIcon))));
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCalendarEventList();
    super.initState();
  }
```

I had it working at one stage but for some reason it's not populating the calendar anymore. On recollection, only some of the dates populated the calendar. I deleted the ones that worked!(populated). I might be barking up the wrong tree anyway. Here's a picture of my backend and the Map:

Initialising the map `_markedDateMap` with the given date populates the calendar:
`DateTime(2019, 5, 24)`
I've noticed that the DateTime object has 5 more parameters it can take..ie the time including mini-seconds. These are all set to zero. However if I change one of the fields the date won't populate the calendar. So I think my problem is with the time part(ie not the date) of the timestamp in firestore. For example this works `DateTime(2019, 5, 24,0,0,0,0,0)` but this doesn't `DateTime(2019, 5, 24,12,0,0,0,0)` I suppose my question can be summarised as how to represent `DateTime(2019, 5, 24,0,0,0,0,0)` in firestore as a timestamp

```
EventList<Event> _markedDateMap = new EventList<Event>(events: {
  new DateTime(2019, 5, 24): [
    new Event(
      date: new DateTime(2019, 1, 24),
      title:'hi',
      icon: _eventIcon,
    )
  ]
});
```

[image]